# How to label a categorical variable in r after label encoding

Tags: r, random-forest

I am working with a large dataset (26 847 instances and 16 features). Some os those features are categorical and some are numeric. I am attempting to run a Random Forest ensemble with this dataset, however, most of the categorical features have way more than the amount of classes supported by randomForests. I was advised to use label encoding on these features, and so I did, using the CatEncoders package (`code: lab_enc1 = LabelEncoder.fit(dataset$feature)`).

I am now having difficulty in associating the label encoding labels to the corresponding feature in the original dataset. I have tried to use "`use_labels`" and "`apply_labels`" from the "`expss`" package and this error appears:

> Error in UseMethod("apply_labels") : 
>     no applicable method for 'apply_labels' applied to an object of class "factor"

Any advice on how I should fix this error?

Comment: I don't know about that package, but in base R you can use `model.frame` and `model.matrix` functions to create dummy variables.

Comment: `apply_labels` and `use_labels` from `expss` are for absolutely another purposes than encode categories. I can advice you to use ranger package (https://cran.r-project.org/package=ranger) for RandomForest. It doesn't have limitations on the number of classes. Or, you could combine levels of your variables manually with conditional assignment.

Comment: That seems to be working! Thank you very much!